# Downloading and/or importing R data from github

Tags: r, github, import, download

I want to download and/or import the plist.RData from [pslmData](https://github.com/myaseen208/pslmData/tree/master/PSLM13-14). I used the following command in R

```
githubURL <- "https://github.com/myaseen208/pslmData/tree/master/PSLM13-14/plist.RData"
load(url(githubURL))
```

which throws the following error:

```
Error in load(url(githubURL)) : 
  the input does not start with a magic number compatible with loading from a connection
```

Then I used the following the method given [here](https://github.com/opetchey/RREEBES/wiki/Reading-data-and-code-from-an-online-github-repository), got the following error:

```
library(repmis)
source_data("https://github.com/myaseen208/pslmData/tree/master/PSLM13-14/plist.RData?raw=True")
```

which gives the following error:

```
Downloading data from: https://github.com/myaseen208/pslmData/tree/master/PSLM13-14/plist.RData?raw=True 

SHA-1 hash of the downloaded data file is:
b1a116e10c224d3e37c34567e73fd632b355c301
Error in load(data, envir = envir, ...) : 
  bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
In addition: Warning message:
file ‘filebb24b83d1f5’ has magic number ''
  Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated
```

I wonder how to download and/or import this data. Thanks

Comment: Just use the download url: `githubURL <- "https://github.com/myaseen208/pslmData/raw/master/PSLM13-14/plist.RData"`

Comment: Thanks @hannes101 for useful comment. It works like a charm. Would appreciate if you change your comment to answer. Thanks

Comment: Linked post is not about RData file, but the issue is the same, we need to link to "raw" data file and not the webpage.